# Translating Roots into Complex Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck finding the irrational roots to this particular equation...

$P(x)=x^6+3x^5-5x^4+7x^3+15x^2-20x-13 = 0$

I've got the values from the graph, but I know I can be more specific by factoring them out... I'm just unsure how? I thought I could factor out a quadratic root using synthetic division, but I'm unfortunately stuck.

Precalculus student studying for the final exam; this was a homework problem I previously got wrong and have spent too much time thinking about. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E6%2B3x%5E5-5x%5E4%2B7x%5E3%2B15x%5E2-20x-13%3D0) doesn't know any closed-form expressions for the roots.

Comment: Synthetic division will work.  If you have at least two roots, the rest is obtainable, but I doubt if you have run into the methods for third and fourth degree polynomials.